# Textbox returns null value on button click in chrome if there is no click event in page

Tags: html, google-chrome, textbox

My login screen have username and password textbox and submit button. Focus is set to Username textbox on page load. But on clicking submit button username textbox returns null value even if it has value. It is not happening with IE. If a keypress or mouseclick is done after page load, then username textbox will return the correct value.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show us your code to make sure where gone wrong

Comment: @Kasnady..apologies for not sharing code because of organization policy... the logic behind the code is just taking the textbox value (textboxid.GetValue()) using jquery. If I am clicking once in textbox  after page load, it works fine. If there is no other click events, it throws null in the 1st textbox entry. Is this a known issue? could you please help to make a mouse click on the username textbox using javascript after page load.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username">
    <input type="text" placeholder="password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

If you provide a little bit more information about your project i could help you with the handling of the code (php, ajax etc)